# What is the math required to do 4d rotations?

Tags: matrices, rotations, quaternions

I recently wondered how I could calculate 4d rotations. I know that matrices and quaternions could be used to do so, but I haven't really found anything clear and specific about what I want.

Basically, I'd like to get from the coordinates of a point $(x,y,z,w)$, to the coordinates of that point, rotated by an angle $θ$, by the desired plane of rotation. ($xy, xz, xw, yz, yw$ or $zw$).

What could be the easiest formula to do so, with matrices and/or quaternions?

Comment: If you are just rotating a coordinate plane, say the xy-plane, by , then you just need the formula for rotation within a 2-dimensional plane — which I suspect you know. The remaining coordinates (z, w) will not change under such a rotation.

Comment: If you want to perform just a simple rotation that fixes the vectors in the $xy$ plane, then can't you simply rotate the vector $(z,w)$ in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: It's not rotating inside a plane, otherwise there's no interest. It's not even real 4d rotation. I'm rotating along these planes, cause in 4d, it's not center of rotation (2d), axis of rotation (3d) but plane of rotation. Idk what all of you tried to mean...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space#Hopf_coordinates) there is the example in case the $xy$ plane is the invariant plane

Comment: I am aware of that, if I asked here it's to obviously get concise answers with explanations. Wikipedia usually isn't really helpful into learning a new thing in math

Comment: Is this euclidean 4d or 3d projective space (3+1) coords?

Comment: Euclidean 4d space

Comment: For n-dimensional rotations, you would use geometric algebra (CL4) and a thing called a rotor instead of a quaternion. Quaternions do rotations in 3D only. (https://geometricalgebra.org/quaternions.html) and (https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/clifford/d4/transforms/index.htm)

Comment: Quaternions also provide all possible 4-dimensional rotations R(p,q) via x |—> pxq for p, q unit-norm quaternions. In this case the only non-uniqueness occurs because R(p,q) = R(-p,-q) for all p, q ∈ S^3. Which shows that the rotation group SO(4) is topologically equivalent to (S^3 × S^3) / (x,y)~(-x,-y), which is double-covered by S^3 × S^3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a R function performing such a rotation:

```
# rotation around the plane (axis1,axis2)
rotation4Dplane <- function(axis1, axis2, theta, vector){
  # normalize the two axes
  c1 <- c(crossprod(axis1))
  c2 <- c(crossprod(axis2))
  axis1 <- axis1/sqrt(c1)
  axis2 <- axis2/sqrt(c2)
  #
  vx <- sum(vector*axis1)
  vy <- sum(vector*axis2)
  coef1 <- vx * cos(theta) - vy * sin(theta)
  coef2 <- vy * cos(theta) + vx * sin(theta)
  pvector <- vx*axis1 + vy*axis2 
  coef1*axis1 + coef2*axis2 + (vector-pvector)
}
# example: rotation of (1, 2, 3, 4) around the plane xy with angle pi/4
rotation4Dplane(c(1, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 1, 0, 0), pi/4, c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Maybe you don't know the R language but I think the syntax is intuitive enough. Tell me if you don't understand and I'll update this answer to translate in maths.

Answer (score 0):

By "plane of rotation" it sounds like you want every point in that plane to remain fixed, as the axis of rotation remains fixed for a 3-d rotation.  The complement would then be a plane being rotated by $\theta$

That means, after choosing a basis containing two basis vectors for the fixed plane, the transformation matrix would look like this:

$\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)&0&0 \\
-\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)&0&0 \\
0&0& 1&0 \\
0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

where the upper left hand corner is doing a rotation on the plane complementary to the fixed plane by $\theta$.

So, given your starting coordinates and subspace, you could

1. Change basis to an orthonormal basis with two vectors that are an orthonormal basis of the fixed subspace in the 3rd and 4th positions
2. Apply the above rotation
3. Unapply the change of basis.

Comment: What would be the rotation matrix of all 6 different planes of rotation? And if I do multiple rotations at once, how shall I compute it?

Comment: Well, the one above fixes the $z-w$ plane. $\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)&0&\sin(\theta)&0 \\
0&1& 0&0 \\
-\sin(\theta)&0&\cos(\theta)&0 \\
0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ would fix the $y-w$ plane.  I think you can work the rest out.  I don't have an example worked out, but I think you need to be ready for the composition of two such things not to have a fixed _plane_.  If you want to compose them you'll just have to decide on an order and do them one after the other.